# Recieving and Sending Data to Azure IOT HUB

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub

I am working on a project which involves receiving data from a sensor and sending it to IoT Hub using Raspberry PI. But beacuse I receive around 10 samples per second from sensor, there is small latency in uploading the data to IoT hub which results in losing around 5 samples. So, I was thinking to store the data for every 10 seconds in a new CSV using one process and reading and sending it to Cloud by another process. This might mean two processes working together. Would this be possible. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You don't mention which Azure IoT SDK you are using, assuming you are using one of them.

Comment: @Georgy You need to be more elaborate like how you are sending the messages and what mechanism are you using lke C2D or twin updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the asynchronous version of the SDK you are using to avoid losing measurements. A coroutine that keeps collecting data from the sensor and push it in a queue and another coroutine that pushes the data from the queue to the IoT hub as it goes along.

Comment: Do you have any links or references for something similar. I am pretty new to this and I am kinda stuck. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the delay, if you are using Python you can find example here for the async version of the sdk : https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/main/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/send_message.py
For create task in asyncio (to run collecting and sending message in pseudo parallel code execution): https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html 
Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Would there be anyway to collect data from two senors at same time and send to IoT hub. I used one sensor and its working fine. But now my project requires to add one more sensor. The major problem is I want the timestamp to be same for the data from two sensors. Like I want to look at data at both sensors at exactly same time. So would it be possible to run two async functions at same time, with both gathering data and sending it after a while ?

Comment: it's difficult to measure two sensors exactly at the same time (at the same nanosecond), but if it's ok to have millisecond precision, you can have an async function that takes care of measuring the two sensors (one after the other but measuring a sensor should not take more than 10ms), and put it in a queue value + timestamp , and the other async function that retrieves it from the queue and publishes it on Iot hub.